# How to change sheet names without losing graph reference with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, graph, openpyxl

I'm trying to write some code that will change sheet names in an excel file based on the data in another excel file.
At first this worked fine;

```
Sheet_names = "A","B","C","D"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name.xlsx)

for i in range (1, len(Sheet_names)):
  Name_change = wb["Sheet{}".format(str(i))]
  wb.active = Name_change
  Name_change.title = "{}".format(Sheet_names[i])

wb.save((file_name.xlsx))
wb.close()
```

But for some reason (I'm unsure what I've changed) a graph within the excel file isn't updating. So the data reference is still to Sheet1, Sheet2 etc.
Im also getting a warning message that there are external links - I guess it's assuming the sheet references are external? The excel file comes from a template that's copied across.
Changing it manually isn't an option, Is having Openpyxl recreate the graph for every sheet the only option?

Out of ideas, help!

Comment: All the data in a chart refers to sheets by name, so if you change the sheet name, you'll have to update the chart references. Unfortunately, there is no easy way of doing this.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'm sure it was doing it automatically previously but perhaps I just didn't notice that the graphs were broken. Thanks for your answer!